# Greek Times New Roman

Tags: greek, times

I am writting Greek in LaTeX using

```
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
```

I want to change the font to Times New Roman or something similar. I already tried

```
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

But these convert only the English characters.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Hello there, welcome to the site. It's much better to use the code sample markdown (highlight the code and hit Ctrl + k or use the button (the one like {})). This will give proper syntax highlighting, display linebreaks and white space and generally be a lot more reader friendly. Also, it's always a + if you include a *full* [MWE (Minimal Working Example)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) rather than just snippets, although it isn't such a big deal here, but it still would have been nice to have a testable document

Answer (score 3):

Imho the best is to switch to xelatex or lualatex:

```
%utf8 encoded!
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}
Ελλάδα
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tempora`. I recommend switching to UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-7, in any case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora}

\begin{document}

Some English text

\begin{otherlanguage*}{greek}
Ελλάδα
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also need math, add

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```